# Least habitable planet / planetary satellite in the Solar System, and how to build a military research base on it

Tags: science-based, technology, hard-science

Taking inspiration from science fiction video games like "DOOM" (base on Mars / Phobos) and "Wolfenstein: The New Colossus" (base on Venus).

My world so far:
Earth is ruled under a global corporatocracy, where companies control all aspects of life for everyone on the planet (much like The Board in "The Outer Worlds", think of the United States Senate, but instead of Senators there are CEOs). They control military, science research, global economy, energy, finance, etc.
Many government research laboratories and think tanks (analogous to Oak Ridge or Los Alamos, energy / weapons / policy research) are located off-Earth, on planetary objects not typically habitable for humans, in order to discourage political or corporate espionage. Ignoring the process with which the staff of these laboratories is determined, all employees at an off-world laboratory are assumed to be there voluntarily.

My main issue is: since *unassisted* human habitation is impossible on these planets / satellites,  it requires lots of technology and vast amounts of power to be able to successfully run / inhabit.

Two questions:

1. What planets / planetary satellites in the Solar System would be the most dangerous / least likely to set up a base on?
2. How would you power a military / government research base on that planet, using only the materials / characteristics of the planet at your disposal (i.e. if it's windy all the time, could you cover much of the planet with high-efficiency wind turbines, etc.)

If anything needs clarification, feel free to ask!

Comment: This is going to be opinion based. My vote is for Jupiter.

Comment: There isn't really an objective standard of 'least habitable', so the question really can't be answered as you've written it. It also can't be answered with knowing the limits of technology that are available to the people building this thing, and what specific threats they're trying to mitigate by location. You could put the thing in the Oort cloud, or in Jupiter's atmosphere or something, but that might be counterproductive to actually being able to do research there at all.

Comment: Mercury is literally on fire during the day at 427 degrees Celsius and below 173 degrees Celsius at night. The surface is geologically inactive much like our moon and the planet is tidally locked with the sun. In this case at a 3:1 ratio,meaning the planet only rotates 3 times per 2 full orbits around the sun. With the polar regions never seeing the sun at all. With no atmosphere,no water and such extreme temperatures it is highly unlikely anyone would want to set up a base on Mercury. But you did ask for danger. Also welcome to the stack exchange.

Comment: What do you mean by on a planet? With Alexander's suggestion, are you actually on a planet if you're in it's atmosphere and never touch ground?

Comment: P.s. you probably want to remove your second question and ask it specifically for the body you decide to settle your base on. They don't like multiple questions around here.

Comment: VTLO. I would argue that "we probably wouldn't put a base on X due to <reasons>" can generally be qualified. In particular, we can enumerate the problems, estimate the difficulty of overcoming them, and compare those costs. (But note Muuski's comment...)

Comment: @Matthew this can be somewhat _qualified_, but can this be objectively _quantified_ so we can have a winner?

Comment: @Alexander, I'd argue it's *plausible*, though coming up with hard numbers is probably beyond the capability of most of us. I don't really see it being notably more opinionated than a lot of the questions on the site, though. Anyway, I've voted, you've voted, others will vote...

Comment: @Alexander: You can't build a base ON Jupiter, or any of the gas giants, as there's (probably) nothing there to build on.  Though possibly you could have something floating on a layer of metallic hydrogen, if such indeed exists.  Given the !10,000 K and  pressure is ~200 GPa pressure, there might be a few engineering challenges to overcome :-)

Comment: @jamesqf Sure. However, there is still a good chance that underneath the layer of metallic hydrogen there's a solid core.

Comment: @Alexander: Possibly. So at the liquid/solid boundary we have a few more engineering challenges, like dealing with ~36000K temperature and 3,000–4,500 GPa pressure.  Then too, according to theoretical calculations, liquid metallic hydrogen is a good solvent, so you get your base down there and find that it's dissolving around you.

Comment: @jamesqf you see why my vote is for Jupiter? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have divided planets and satellites into too easy, too hard, and feasibly nasty.

**Gas giants - too hard:** Jupiter, Saturn, Uranus, Neptune - implausible that any realistic base could be situated on the planetary surface due to enormous pressures involved. So the base would have to float or fly. That also seems implausible for unassisted habitation as, although it might be possible to power the habitation there would be little/no access to raw materials for repair/maintenance/growth.

**Venus - too hard:** Implausible on the surface due to temperature - no realistic way to cool the base that is consistent with the laws of thermodynamics. For a floating/flying base the problems are similar to those on the gas giants.

**Rocky planets and satellites in general - too easy:** Generally plausible if you can survive in an atmosphere dome (or underground), extract water from the local crust, use solar radiation for energy etc. So the Moon, Mars, larger asteroids, and many moons might not be a sufficient challenge. Mercury fits into that category too, so long as you situate your base is near a pole where the temperature range won't be too outlandish (although I am not sure of the presence of water in Mercury's crust).

**Icy and cold planets/satellites - too easy:** Also generally plausible as above. A bit more effort to get sufficient energy from solar if the body is far from the sun (Pluto etc.), but that is more an issue of cost in setting up systems rather than additional risk/difficulty in operation.

**Titan - much too easy** - lots of petrochemicals for raw materials.

**So my choice would be:**

***Io*** - the most volcanically active body in the solar system. It has all the usual challenges of living on a body in near vacuum but adds the complication of an unstable crust and the chance that at any time the base could be subjected to mega-earthquakes, pyroclastic flows, lava flows, flying ejecta (volcanic 'fallout' can extend hundreds of km on Io) and the chance that a new volcano could errupt near/under the base at any time.

With regard to a power supply for a base on Io - I think that a geothermal power station would add just the right combination of technical feasibility and operational hazard.